# Stuck at Asus boot logo after restart but boot after shutdown is fine

Tags: boot, asus, restart, nvidia-geforce

I have a problem with restarts on my [ASUS ROG GL533-VD-Q725-CB](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ROG-GL553VD/specifications/) gaming laptop ([manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/GL553VW/0409_E11734_GL553VW_A.pdf)) with a NVIDA GeForce GTX 1050 4GB GPU. It does the same with Ubuntu, Kubuntu,  or Ubuntu MATE; with versions 18.04.3 LTS, 19.04, and 19.10 (beta).

Ubuntu starts fine from a shutdown, but when I restart, it stalls at the Asus logo, and stays there until I force shutdown the PC and start again.  I tried with secure boot on and off, fast boot on and off, but neither helped.

How may I troubleshoot to resolve this?

Comment: Is this Dual Boot with Windows?

Comment: No, Ubuntu only.

I already tried reinstalling Windows again and it boots ok from a restart.
But I hate Windows, so I stick with Linux even if restarts doesn't work.